# cannot access Postgres views from SSIS thru ODBC PSQL driver

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, view, ssis, odbc

I'm working with Postgres from SSIS thru ODBC Unicode driver ver 13.01.  32-bit connection.

I can successfully connect to all Postgres tables but **can not able to see any view** thru that connection.

How can I access to Postgres views from SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using the SQL Server import wizard (which uses a subset of SSIS) and I also could not see any views in the list of "Tables and views" for my PostgreSQL database

[image]

but when I chose the "Write a query to specify the data to transfer" and entered

```sql
SELECT * FROM view1
```

for the "SQL statement" it allowed be to import the view data into a SQL Server table.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem because the view belonged to another user and the search context in postgres was not set for my ssis-login user.

Regards